# Git Find if last commit was from a Merge from a Specific Branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm setting up a Bitbucket Pipeline and it has useful YML functions to kick of valodations from `Pull Requests` and to kick off deployments form commits to a branch. One thing I can't seem to find is a way of checking when a branch get's updated via a commit, if the commit came from a merge of branch-X into my updated branch branch-Y. I'd like to know if the commit came from a `Pull Request` from a specific branch or if it came from a merge from a specific branch (branch-X being the source).

I was thinking if I can't do this natively with Bitbucket's YAML pipeline commands, that I could use **git** to check this. With in git commands: is there a way to check what was the source of a commit to a specific branch? If it came from a merge from a specific branch or from a `Pull Request` from that branch.

My branches will always retain the same names therefore we could say if I merge branch-X into branch-Y, I can find out via git if the commit to branch-Y came from a merge of Branch-Y.

I'm not sure if this is possible but thought I'd check if anyone knows.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way looking at the commits :

If branch-Y is on a merge commit, you can get the hash of the commit that was merged into branch-Y :

```
# 'commit^2' means : the 2nd parent of 'commit'
mcommit=$(git rev-parse branch-Y^2)
```

You can then check if this commit matches the current state of an existing branch :

```
git show-ref | grep $mcommit
# if 'refs/remotes/origin/branch-X' appears in the results, then 'branch-X' is a candidate
```

This will work if, when gitlab gets notified and updates its branches, branch-X is still in the state it was when it was merged.

Also : if two branches point at `mcommit`, you will not be able to distinguish which one was actually merged.

---

Another way is to look for information in the commit message :

if you have a template message on PRs which clearly mentions the the branch that was merged, or the PR id, you can probably use this info more easily.